# Register Designate with Keystone

Tags: openstack

I have followed the following Guide for Setup of designate.

http://docs.openstack.org/developer/designate/install/ubuntu.html

Above guide is having the exact workflow what I was looking for.

I need to setup Designate using PowerDns Backend. It provides way for doing the same.

But In case of Registering Designate with Keystone it lacks in Detail.

Please some one help me regarding the same.

Now I am trying to access http://IP.Address:9001/v2/command.

It gives error as follows:

**Authentication required**

Error log from designate-api:

```
2015-10-20 03:58:36.917 20993 WARNING keystoneclient.middleware.auth_token [-] Unable to find authentication token in headers
2015-10-20 03:58:36.917 20993 INFO keystoneclient.middleware.auth_token [-] Invalid user token - rejecting request
2015-10-20 03:58:36.917 20993 INFO eventlet.wsgi [-] 61.12.45.30 - - [20/Oct/2015 03:58:36] "GET /v1/ HTTP/1.1" 401 217 0.000681
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the way for doing the same.

Here it is detailed steps attached.

Registering keystone with designate:

Kestone Setup:

```
apt-get install keystone
```

Edit /etc/keystone/keystone.conf and change the [database] section:

```
connection = mysql://keystone:keystone@localhost/keystone


rm /var/lib/keystone/keystone.db

$ mysql -u root -p

mysql> CREATE DATABASE keystone;

mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON keystone.* TO 'keystone'@'localhost' \
  IDENTIFIED BY 'keystone';

mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON keystone.* TO 'keystone'@'%' \
  IDENTIFIED BY 'keystone';

mysql> exit

pip install mysql-python

su -s /bin/sh -c "keystone-manage db_sync" keystone
```

Execute the following command note down the value:

```
openssl rand -hex 10
```

Edit /etc/keystone/keystone.conf and change the [DEFAULT] section, replacing ADMIN_TOKEN with the results of the command:

```
[DEFAULT]
# A "shared secret" between keystone and other openstack services
admin_token = ADMIN_TOKEN
```

Configure the log directory. Edit the /etc/keystone/keystone.conf file and update the [DEFAULT] section:

```
[DEFAULT]
...
log_dir = /var/log/keystone


service keystone restart
```

Users tenants service and endpoint creation:

```
export OS_SERVICE_TOKEN=token_value
(please edit the token value generated above)


export OS_SERVICE_ENDPOINT=http://localhost:35357/v2.0


keystone tenant-create --name service --description "Service Tenant" --enabled true


keystone service-create --type dns --name designate --description="Designate"


keystone endpoint-create --service designate --publicurl http://127.0.0.1:9001/v1 --adminurl http://127.0.0.1:9001/v1 --internalurl http://127.0.0.1:9001/v1


keystone user-create --name dnsaas --tenant service --pass dnsaas --enabled true


keystone role-create --name=admin


keystone user-role-add --user dnsaas --tenant service --role admin



apt-get install python-designateclient
```

Create an openrc file:

```
$ vi openrc


export OS_USERNAME=dnsaas
export OS_PASSWORD=dnsaas
export OS_TENANT_NAME=service
export OS_AUTH_URL=http://localhost:5000/v2.0/
export OS_AUTH_STRATEGY=keystone
export OS_REGION_NAME=RegionOne
```

source an openrc file:

```
. openrc
```

**Note :**

**Execute or restart the designate-central and designate-api services.**

**designate domain-list command**

```
designate domain-list
```

Above command is not returing any errors means fine to go.